# Как выбрать все столбцы в которых есть NAN?

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите, как из фрейма данных выбрать только те колонки, в которых есть NaN, и сформировать из них другой фрейм данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно так:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
     a  b    c  d
0  NaN  3  NaN  7
1  0.0  3  5.0  5
2  4.0  7  7.0  9
3  NaN  2  NaN  4
4  6.0  6  3.0  7
5  5.0  0  4.0  1
6  NaN  3  NaN  8
7  0.0  7  9.0  7
8  4.0  5  8.0  3
9  NaN  2  NaN  6

In [16]: nans = df.loc[:, df.isnull().any()].copy()

In [17]: nans
Out[17]:
     a    c
0  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  5.0
2  4.0  7.0
3  NaN  NaN
4  6.0  3.0
5  5.0  4.0
6  NaN  NaN
7  0.0  9.0
8  4.0  8.0
9  NaN  NaN
```

Пошагово:

```
In [18]: df.isnull()
Out[18]:
       a      b      c      d
0   True  False   True  False
1  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
3   True  False   True  False
4  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False
6   True  False   True  False
7  False  False  False  False
8  False  False  False  False
9   True  False   True  False

In [19]: df.isnull().any()
Out[19]:
a     True
b    False
c     True
d    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Второй раз меня выручаешь.